# Import local files from hard drive in Spotify

Tags: hard-drive, spotify

I'm trying to import files from an external Hard Drive to Spotify. 
In the Local Files dialog, I add the path to the directory in the mounted external HD that I want to include in Spotify. (For example: `/media/username/diskname/Spotify`)

I don't get any error, and the path just included appears in the preferences panel, toggled on.
But my Local Files tab is empty.

I've found several answers about this topic in the Spotify forum, but all of those were for older versions of Ubuntu (I'm using 18.04), for example: [Linux Local files do not play on Ubuntu 16.04](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Desktop-Linux/Linux-Local-files-do-not-play-on-Ubuntu-16-04-SOLVED/td-p/1343831)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you likely have is that the Spotify client does not have permissions to read from directories outside your home directory.

The easiest way to fix your problem is probably mounting your drive to a folder within your home directory:

```
# unmount drive
sudo umount /media/username/diskname
# Create mountpoint under ~
mkdir ~/mnt/diskname
# Mount the drive
sudo mount /dev/sdX ~/mnt/diskname
```